# SemantiUI: Sidebar flyout menu

Tags: sidebar, semantic-ui

I am trying to get a Fly-out type menu launched from a sidebar.  Any ideas/examples?  Wondering if Popups are an option?

Ex:  When user has their mouse over the settings icon, I want a menu to "fly-out" with the 3 options..,

```
<div id="mnuSideNav" class="ui vertical menu labeled icon inverted sidebar">
 <div id="mnuAdmin" class="item ">
    <i class="settings icon" title="Administrative Settings"></i>
    <div id="mnuAdminItems" class="inverted menu">
      <a class="item"><i class="edit icon"></i> Edit Profile</a>
      <a class="item"><i class="globe icon"></i> Choose Language</a>
      <a class="item"><i class="settings icon"></i> Account Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this using a popup..,

Elements like that support overflow cannot have menus extend beyond the sidebar ("Fly-out").  So Pop-ups are the only option.  Define a popup and in the javascript initializing the popup set its popup parameter..,

Ex:  SideBar:

```
<div id="mnuSideNav" class="ui left vertical menu labeled icon inverted sidebar">  
  <a id="sbAdmin" class="browse item popupMenu">
    <i class="settings icon" title="Administrative Settings"></i>       
  </a>
</div>
```

Popup

```
<div id="adminPopup" class="ui popup  ">
  <div class="ui one column relaxed equal height left aligned grid  ">
    <div class="ui column ">
      <h4 class="ui header">Admin Menu</h4>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.popupMenu').popup({
        popup: '#adminPopup',
        inline   : true,
        hoverable: true,
        position : 'right center',  
        delay: {show: 300, hide: 800}
    });
```

Comment: This isn't working for me! http://plnkr.co/edit/5c6SnX?p=preview Can you please put together a jsfiddle or plunk so I can see it working in action?